# Cannot convert datatype of value in object

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have create next.js app with using mongoDB as database.

Now as in my code, I when the button have been click submit all the data will just show in table. I have extract all the data that I want to calculate seperately such as `product_unit` and `product_price`. But, because the value have been `push` in `productList` as text. I cannot calculate it.

I try to use `.parseInt` to convert but it does not work.

What should I do?

My Code:

```
const [jsxProductList, setJsxProductList] = useState(<tr></tr>);
const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);

const onSubmitToDatabase = (data) => {
    console.log({ productList })
    fetch('/api/stock',
       {
           method: 'post',
           body: productList
       })
    }

const onSubmit = (data) => {

let j = 1
for (let i = 1; i <= productList.length; i++) {
  j++
}

var start_item_id = j
let p = { id: start_item_id, product_name: data.product_name, code: data.code, brand: 'Honda', model: 'CBR150', qty: data.qty, unitPrice: 100 }
productList.push(p)
console.log("productList", productList.length)
let newList = productList.map(p => {
  console.log("Update JSX", p)
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{p.id}</td>
      <td>{p.product_name}</td>
      <td>{p.code}</td>
      <td>{p.brand}</td>
      <td>{p.model}</td>
      <td>{p.qty}</td>
      <td>{p.unitPrice}</td>
    </tr>
  )
})
setProductList(productList)
setJsxProductList(newList)

const product_code = []
const product_price = []
const product_unit = []
productList.map(p => {
  product_code.push(p.code)
  product_price.push(p.unitPrice)
  product_unit.push(p.qty)
})

product_unit.map(h => (
  h.parseInt
))

let total_unit, total_price = 0
for (let k = 0; k < product_unit.length; k++) {
  total_unit = total_unit + product_unit[k]
}}

for (let k = 0; k < product_price.length; k++) {
  total_unit = total_unit + product_unit[k]
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const new_product_unit = product_unit.map(h => parseInt(h));

// now use "new_product_unit" later in your code
```